# Localization of resultLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, formatting

I am developing application for iOS 7. I am new to developing so I don't understand all of it.

This is the code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

NSString *postotakString = [postotak text];

float postotakFloat = [[postotakString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];

NSString *cijeliBrojString = [cijeliBroj text];

float cijeliBrojFloat = [[cijeliBrojString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];

float formulaPostotak = (cijeliBrojFloat/(postotakFloat/100));

[formatter setFormatWidth:2];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;

NSString *rez = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:formulaPostotak]];

[rezultat setText:rez];

return ;
```

Users input Original Price and a discount. In Labels where it prints results the format is: 1.000.000,00

I want when users have Base localization to have this format: 1,000,000.00 and for people with Croatian to have this: 1.000.000,00

Is this possible? Can I do it with if statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you defining as user's with "Base localization"? I'm not familiar with the rules of Croatia and number formatting. The language can also affect the number formatting of a locale. For example, a locale of fr_CA versus en_CA results in two different number formats. The typical method when handling the localization of numbers is let NSNumberFormatter use the current locale of the device, which it does by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NSLocale` property of the number formatter:

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

If the current locale is Croatia, it will show the numbers as appropriate.

Comment: No need to set to the current locale. An NSNumberFormatter will automatically use the current locale, unless you override it.